# Given a large block of text with links, And I want to extract the links, should I use FE or BE?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a large block of HTML. I want to extract a list of all the links within the block of text. Should I use the backend, rails or should I use the frontend, jQuery and process on the client end of every page load?

Pros/cons? thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you're trying to do with the links, but I'd tend to use Ruby rather than Javascript, especially Javascript in the browser.

You tend to have more resources on the server to do this processing, you can shuffle it off to a background job in order to free yourself up for incoming requests and by using Nokogiri, you aren't sacrificing any text processing power.